# Directional derivative of composite function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, normed-spaces

> Let $X$ be a normed space and $a\in X$. Function $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and bounded, and $g:X \to X$ has directional derivative in point $a$ along the vector $v$. Find a directional derivative in point $a$ of function $f \circ g$ along the vector $v$.

So, from the statement of the problem I know that $\lim_\limits{t\to 0} \dfrac{\|g(a+tv)-g(a)\|}{t} = l$ exists, but I am not quite sure how to manipulate expression $\lim_\limits{t\to 0} \dfrac{f( g(a+tv)) - f(g(a))}{t}$ to find what I want. I've tried to multiply by $\dfrac{\|g(a+tv)-g(a)\|}{\|g(a+tv)-g(a)\|}$ and then compute $\lim_\limits{t\to 0} \dfrac{f( g(a+tv)) - f(g(a))}{\|g(a+tv)-g(a)\|}$ $\cdot$ $\dfrac{\|g(a+tv)-g(a)\|}{t}$ but this didn't seem to lead anywhere. I don't really have any other ideas what to do.

EDIT: We shall prove that $f$ must be differentiable at $a$. Assume opposite, that $f$ isn't differentiable at $a$. Let $X = (-2, 2) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $a = 0$, $v = 1$. Using functions $g: X\to X$ defined as $g(x) = x$ and $f: X\to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x) = |x|$  we get that $l = 1$ and above limit is equal to $\lim_\limits{t\to 0} \dfrac{f(a+tv) - f(a)}{a+tv-a}$ $\cdot$ $1$ = $\lim_\limits{t\to 0} \dfrac{f(a+tv) - f(a)}{tv}$, so, if there exits a directional derivative in point $a$ of function $f \circ g$ along the vector $v$ function $f$ must be differentiable $($because $\lim_\limits{t\to 0} \dfrac{f(a+tv) - f(a)}{tv} = \lim_\limits{h\to 0} \dfrac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h}$ is derivarive of $f$ at point $a$, by definiton$)$, but we know that the function $f$ isn't differentiable at point $0$, hence, we got a contradiction. So $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and the directional derivative we wanted to find is equal to $f'(g(a))\cdot l$

Comment: You have to use the chain rule. Do the calculation when $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $X = \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: But I don't know if $f$ is differentiable

Comment: Find a counterexample if $f$ is not assumed to be differentiable.

Comment: From function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $g(x) = x$ I should conclude that $f$ is differentiable, right?

Comment: Don’t guess. When you think something might be true, try to prove it yourself. If you don’t succeed, try to show it’s false. After you’ve tried both ways a few times, then ask.

Comment: I've made an edit, hopefully you can check it. I don't think this is completely valid proof because I didn't use the fact that $f$ is continuous and bounded.

Comment: Looks good, but you should find a specific example of a function $f$ that is continuous and bounded, which confirms what you say in the last paragraph. Remember, a good way to disprove something is to find a counterexample, preferably a simple one.

Comment: I think everything is added and example is clear now. I am just confused that I didn't directly use that $f$ is continuous and bounded, and I can't think of an example where $f$ isn't continious or bounded but directional derivative exits.

Comment: A counterexample is a pair of functions $f$ and $g$ that satisfy the assumptions but not the conclusion. Your choice of $g$ is good. Now all you need is a function $f$. The assumption on $f$ is that it is continuous and bounded, and the conclusion is that $f\circ g$ is differentiable.

Comment: I found such a function $f$ and made a new edit. But how can I be sure that there don't exist functions $f$ and $g$ that satisfy the assumptions, the conclusion and that $f$ is not dfferentiable?

Comment: To disprove a statement, you need only one counterexample

Comment: Your example is a good one.

Comment: Your final sentence does not follow from the counter-example, Just because the statement is not true in general if you don't assume $f$ is differentiable at $g(a)$, does not mean that $f$ has to be differentiable at $g(a)$ for the statement to be true. It is possible that the lack of differentiability of $f$ at $a$ is due to a problem in a different direction than $\left.\frac{dg}{dv}\right|_a$. For example, $$a=(0,0), v = (1,0), g(x,y) = (x,0), f(x,y) = x + |y|$$

Comment: That's why I said I was confused, but I don't know what to do now.